# Zip all files in a directory, but don't include the top directory in the archive

Tags: unix, terminal, zip

Can't quite figure out how to do this right. I have a folder with a website in `/var/www`

I want to create a zip file with all of it, which when I decompress it does not include the top directory. In other words, the "top" of the zip file should not be the `www` directory, but the files inside that directory. Hope that made sense...

Reason why I need it is because I need to upload my website as a zip file and then unzip it in place. And won't work if it then unzips to `webroot/www/` instead of `webroot/`.

Any able to help with how to do this correctly in the terminal?

Comment: Which commands and arguments are you using to make the Zip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/your/folder/www
zip -r filename.zip *
```

Optionally

```
mv filename.zip /some/other/path
```

Comment: Will this include hidden files?

Comment: * does include hidden files.

Comment: What if I don't want to `cd` to the directory first?

Comment: zip -r -j filename.zip folder_name

Comment: @kodlan Thanks! You should add this as an answer. The `-j` argument solved it for me. From `man zip`: _Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full  path (relative to the current directory)._

Comment: Does not include hidden file/folders

Answer (score 3):

`7z a -tzip filename.zip -w /var/www/.`

Hidden files included.